# pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: 'jsonschema'

Tags: python, python-3.x, intel, jsonschema

unable to get "intel-nauta" running as its throwing this error : pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'jsonschema' distribution was not found and is required by the application
[19160] Failed to execute script main.

python 3.0

> while pip installing jsonschema it says requirement already found.
>   changed the version still error persists.
>   referred the following links.
>   [https://github.com/IntelAI/nauta/blob/develop/docs/user-guide/actions/getting_started.md](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1305)

https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1305

https://github.com/Julian/jsonschema/issues/228

https://github.com/Julian/jsonschema/issues/228

not a great coder pls help.
posting the whole error trail:

```
  File "main.py", line 27, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\****\downloads\nauta\nauta-develop\applications\cli\.venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "commands\experiment\experiment.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\xxxx\downloads\nauta\nauta-develop\applications\cli\.venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "commands\experiment\list.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\xxxx\downloads\nauta\nauta-develop\applications\cli\.venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "commands\experiment\common.py", line 54, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\xxxx\downloads\nauta\nauta-develop\applications\cli\.venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "util\jupyter_notebook_creator.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\xxxxx\downloads\nauta\nauta-develop\applications\cli\.venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "lib\site-packages\nbformat\__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\xxxxx\downloads\nauta\nauta-develop\applications\cli\.venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "lib\site-packages\nbformat\validator.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\xxxxx\downloads\nauta\nauta-develop\applications\cli\.venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "lib\site-packages\jsonschema\__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
  File "lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 481, in get_distribution
  File "lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 357, in get_provider
  File "lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 900, in require
  File "lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 786, in resolve
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'jsonschema' distribution was not found and is required by the application
[11672] Failed to execute script main

C:\Users\xxxxx\Downloads\nauta\nauta-develop\applications\cli\dist>nctl --help
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 27, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\xxxxx\downloads\nauta\nauta-develop\applications\cli\.venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "commands\experiment\experiment.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\xxxxx\downloads\nauta\nauta-develop\applications\cli\.venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "commands\experiment\list.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\xxxxx\downloads\nauta\nauta-develop\applications\cli\.venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "commands\experiment\common.py", line 54, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\xxxxx\downloads\nauta\nauta-develop\applications\cli\.venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "util\jupyter_notebook_creator.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\xxxxx\downloads\nauta\nauta-develop\applications\cli\.venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "lib\site-packages\nbformat\__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\xxxxx\downloads\nauta\nauta-develop\applications\cli\.venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "lib\site-packages\nbformat\validator.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\xxxxx\downloads\nauta\nauta-develop\applications\cli\.venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "lib\site-packages\jsonschema\__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
  File "lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 481, in get_distribution
  File "lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 357, in get_provider
  File "lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 900, in require
  File "lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 786, in resolve
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'jsonschema' distribution was not found and is required by the application
[19160] Failed to execute script main
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with pyinstaller not working with new version jsonschema. There is already a workaround in nauta https://github.com/IntelAI/nauta/commit/8806aaa87a25d17d89a9aa9062571620d63e2b48 where the requirements.txt are forcing jsonschema==2.6.0
Please pull the latest version and try the build again.