# pyinstaller - jsonschema - pandas: 'jsonschema' distribution was not found

Tags: python, pandas, pyinstaller, jsonschema

I try to get an executable with PyInstaller (v4.5) but I get the following error message:

> pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'jsonschema' distribution was
> not found and is required by the application

Similar to
[this issue on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54879457/pkg-resources-distributionnotfound-jsonschema)

My code is just a test-code:

```
import pandas
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.mainloop()
```

The issue is somehow related to the pandas library.
Can anybody help with this issue?

Comment: The error message says you need the 'jsonschema' distribution. Did you try installing that?

Comment: @Ether Yes, that was already pre-installed, but I tried it with different versions as well. But still got the same error message